# Which pre-modern societies have had significant non-domestic roles for women?

Tags: women, gender

In the modern world, the place of women in society has shifted due to the Suffragettes, labour demands of the World Wars, and other specific, relatively recent influences.

In earlier societies, it is often normal for women to have a primarily domestic role.

What exceptions are there to this pattern?

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)   Please revise the question to have an [authoritative answer](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4274/1401)

Comment: Voting to close. This is answered by the "History and Distribution" section of [the Wikipedia article on Matriarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matriarchy).

Comment: This is a good question. That article is about socities where women rule over men, which don't exist and never have. Modern society is not a 'matriarchy' but does, per the question, feature women in significant non-domestic roles.

Comment: At a very minimum, OP should address the examples in Wikipedia.  That's one of the functions of preliminary research. The absence makes me disengage from this as a push question. I'm not inclined to exert time/effort merely to feed someone's desire for an argument. This is History.SE not the [Argument Clinic](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uLlv_aZjHXc)

Comment: Do you consider working in the fields as "a primarily domestic role" ? If not, your premise is false.

Comment: @NeMo, Perhaps a closer read of the page would reveal, "Most anthropologists hold that there are no known societies that are unambiguously matriarchal"; the question is not about matriarchal societies, but about which societies had non-domestic roles.  This is now widely acknowledged; only zealots question that the gender norms esposed by the Victorians are inaccurate, obsolete and misleading.  OP's omission to do preliminary research, plus the format of the question strongly indicate a desire for argument rather than serious inquiry. Let's not feed the trolls.

Answer (score 3):

It was pretty standard in North American Native cultures for it to be considered the [women's job to plant and harvest crops](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prehistoric_agriculture_on_the_Great_Plains#Cultivation_and_yields). Men were reserved for more wide-ranging and dangerous pursuits, such as hunting, trade, raiding, and war<sup>1</sup>. This could be the reason it wasn't at all weird (although not universal) for [Native cultures to be matrilineal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrilineality#Americas).

This caused rather a lot of issues after European contact, as European culture considered native men uncivilized and lazy for not farming themselves, and of course very worried about all that free time native men had to be waging war on each other and European settlers. So a constant goal was to try to get native *men* to do the farming, which Europeans considered more civilized behavior.

For their part native men looked upon all such efforts as attempts to feminize or emasculate them and their cultures, which you can imagine did not tend to go down well at all.

---

<sup>1 - I should point out here that it was [*not* unheard of](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Native_American_women_in_Colonial_America#Gender_roles) for women to participate in these activities too, just unusual.</sup>

Comment: That actually makes sense. Native Americans didn't have much farm animals so they had to work harder (hunting) to get their proteins. So females had to pick up the slack and do the farming. Also, Native American way of farming required less strength - plowing is a job for men because it is intense physical work. In Europe women did do other parts of agricultural work, such as reaping.

Comment: Don't assume men were always the primary hunters: https://journals.plos.org/plosone/article?id=10.1371/journal.pone.0287101

Comment: @BrianZ - I'm guessing the footnote was missed by some people?